# Simple Question UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey everbody. Im getting trouble with a simple thing. But i'm missing some detail. I'm trying to set up the styles of the TableView. I've edited the table on visual, but seems do not take effect what i do.

What im doing wrong?

```
@implementation ComentariosViewController

@synthesize listaComentarios, tabelaComentarios;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [listaComentarios count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //cell.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
}

NSString *cellValue = [listaComentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
tabelaComentarios = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

tabelaComentarios.delegate = self;
tabelaComentarios.dataSource = self;

//bkg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BkgComentarios.png"];


tabelaComentarios.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
//
// Change the properties of the imageView and tableView (these could be set
// in interface builder instead).
//
tabelaComentarios.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
tabelaComentarios.rowHeight = 100;
tabelaComentarios.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientBackground.png"];

//
// Create a header view. Wrap it in a container to allow us to position
// it better.
//
UIView *containerView =
[[[UIView alloc]
  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)]
 autorelease];
UILabel *headerLabel =
[[[UILabel alloc]
  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)]
 autorelease];
headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Comentários", @"");
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[containerView addSubview:headerLabel];
self.tabelaComentarios.tableHeaderView = containerView;

self.view = tabelaComentarios;
}



-(void)loadView{


// XML

listaComentarios = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/dev/mcomm/produto.xml"]] retain];
TBXMLElement * rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

TBXMLElement * comentarios = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"comentarios" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

TBXMLElement * comentario = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"comentario" parentElement:comentarios];


while (comentario) {

    NSString * descText = [TBXML textForElement:comentario];
    NSLog(@"%@", descText);
    [listaComentarios addObject:descText];

    comentario = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"comentario" searchFromElement:comentario];


}



[tbxml release];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

[listaComentarios release];
[tabelaComentarios release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that isn't working for you?

Comment: The TableView. I put it on my view, and setted the size to 300x300, ok?

Comment: But wheni test, it takes all the screen. So, isnt working with my changes.

Comment: If you're creating the table in the interface builder, then you need to be accessing it via an iboutlet, not creating another table in the code.

Comment: Thats it. I've declared it on header. But i dont know where im creating it again via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Interface builder to add the table, try commenting out this line:

```
tabelaComentarios = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```